# Java: executing ffmpeg with command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line, ffmpeg, arguments, execute

I'm trying to execute ffmpeg with several command line arguments. See http://pastebin.com/6RzLL8KQ for the complete program. It takes arguments and will print the correct command, but it will not execute ffmpeg with the correct parameters. However if I test and put `String commandStr[] = {ffmpegpath,"-h"};` it is able to print that without issue. If I run the command on `/home/user/PB200014b.avi` for example, it prints the command `ffmpeg -i /home/user/PB200014b.avi -r 1 -f image2 /home/user/originalframes-PB200014b/%03d.jpg` as it should, but no frames appear in the directory `/home/user/originalframes-PB200014b/`

The relevant lines of my code are lines 71 onward. Thank you for any help you may be able to give!

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine on my computer.
Have you checked error stream of created process in your example?

```
ffmpeg.getErrorStream();
```

May be some errors of ffmpeg itself?